# What is the enol form of 4-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

> What is the enol form of this compound?
>
> [image: (4S)-4-methylcyclohex-2-en-1-one]

I have made an attempt, but it doesn't look quite right.

[image]

Which hydrogen should be taken off (left or right hand side of the carbonyl)? And I don't think the ring is aromatic so I don't know how it is stabilized.

Comment: Why should it be stabilised? I doubt this enol form is more stable than the α,β-unsaturated carbonyl.

Comment: 1) There are two possible enol forms of this compound. 2) Being an enol is not intrinsicly more stable than being a ketone (in fact, ketones are usually more stable than enols) but with a strong base you can deprotonate the system. The enolate will then be more stable. 3) Which hydrogen you take off depends on your base.

Comment: As @Jan points out, there are two possible enols. One (the one you've drawn above) has a hydroxy group located on the diene double bonds; the other (produced by removing the proton on the methylated carbon) has both a hydroxy **and** a methyl group attached to the diene double bonds.  One enol has one more substituent, the methyl group, located on the diene. Methyl groups stabilize double bonds.  Therefore the enol with both the hydroxy and methyl group located on the diene will be the more stable enol and will predominate at equilibrium.

Comment: More substitutes alkenes are more stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also which hydrogen should be taken off (left or right hand side of the carbonyl)? And i dont think the ring is aromatic so i dont know how it is stabilized...

When creating an enol the hydrogen *alpha* relative to the carbonyl is **generally** ionized. The alpha hydrogens are somewhat more acidic than the other hydrogens because of the possibility for resonance withdrawal of electron density by the carbonyl oxygen.

The ring is conjugated, but not fully conjugated, so the ring isn't aromatic. But partial conjugation is stabilizing.

Whether the enol or the keto form of this molecule is more stable requires further consideration; we cannot simply say that one is conjugated and the other is less conjugated and the one that is more conjugated must be more stable.

Comment: It does not have to be $\alpha$ in the presence of an enone system …

Comment: @Jan edited to reflect that fact

Comment: But Dissenter, isn't the OP really asking which of the 2 possible enols is more stable ("What is the enol form of this compound")?

Answer (score 11):

There are two possible enol forms of this ketone. The first one is:

[image]

This is the one you drew, which shows the α hydrogen being abstracted. It is perfectly valid.

The other one is:

[image]

Note how the alkene next to the carbonyl group "extends" the range of the carbonyl group. This allows the γ hydrogen (i.e. the one three carbons away) to be removed, and then you can "push" electrons into the carbonyl group through the alkene group. In general, this is a property of **α,β-unsaturated ketones** (i.e. ketones which have a double bond between the α and β carbons).

Note that in this enol form, the methyl substituent is now in the same plane as the C=C next to it. This means that, if you were to reverse the tautomerisation to get back the keto form, there's an equal chance of the hydrogen coming in from above the plane and from below the plane, and [*racemisation*](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/keto_enol/racem_halo_haloform_alkylierung.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/keto_enol/racem/racem.vscml.html) would occur. In practice, there is a rapid equilibrium between keto and enol forms, and this means that if you were to dissolve this compound in any kind of acid (or base), the racemisation would occur pretty quickly.

Here, I have drawn the mechanisms for acid-catalysed tautomerisation. I assume you are now able to draw the mechanisms for the reaction in base (which in general forms an enolate instead of an enol).

---

At this stage, you might wonder why we cannot abstract the *other* α hydrogen. There's a couple of reasons. Firstly, it's attached to a $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbon, and the C-H bond is therefore somewhat stronger. Secondly, even if you could take off that proton and form the "enol", you would have two double bonds next to each other. That's a huge problem because those double bonds want to be linear, but don't quite have the space to do so since there's a ring:

[image]

---

Regarding the stability of the two legitimate enol forms, I would not say that they are any more stable than the keto form. In general, the keto form is more stable. There are cases in which the enol form is relatively stabilised, most often when there is aromaticity or extra conjugation in the enol form (other factors such as solvent will also influence the position of equilibrium):

[image]

However, that is not the case here. The starting keto form is as conjugated as any enol you can form.

Comment: I was taught that it depends on the solvent whether acetoacetate adopts a diketo or enol form: Diketo in hydrogen-bonding solvents and enol in those solvents that cannot be hydrogen bond donors.

Comment: @Jan hmm, I know it does depend on solvent, but never learnt that little detail. I'll go look it up when I have time.

Comment: Enol form of aceto acetic ester is more stable than the diketo compound because of intramolecular hydrogen bonding between OH and carbonyl Oxygen. The enol form is only stable in non polar medium. In polar solvent, the solvent interrupts the intramolecular Hydrogen bonding. I don't think it's because of conjugation

Comment: Ok, I looked it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimedone has a 67:33 ratio of keto:enol in $\ce{CDCl3}$. In this compound, there's no possibility of intramolecular H-bonding, so the extra stability must come from conjugation (normally, the ratio is $10^5:1$). Presumably, the intramolecular H-bonding in ethyl acetoacetate further stabilises the enol form in a solvent that cannot form hydrogen bonds.

Comment: In basic medium, one possibility is for hydrogen four in the ring (according to iupac name) to get abstracted by the base to form a carbanion at position 4, which is in resonance with the alkene and the carbonyl group, hence in one resonating structure the carbanion will be at carbon number 2 (which was originally sp2 hybridised, the one you talk about). In this position the carbanion could abstract an hydrogen to form a second keto form (4-methylcyclohex-3-en-1-one); although this form is less stable than the other keto/enol forms, it should surely exist in equilibrium, correct?

Comment: (this can also happen in acidic medium, I just find it easier to think in basic medium)

Answer (score -3):

yes your answer is right. this is more stable as it is a conjugated diene. but, initially the H+ attacks on the lone pair of =O then the oxygen takes up the pie bond to neutralize the formal + charge on it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that an electrophile (i.e. H+) attacks anything.

Comment: @Dissenter If it is acid catalysed, it totally does. If not, then there is no electrophile.

Comment: Also it is not necessarily more stable. The carbonyl is also conjugated so just saying that it is a conjugated diene is not enough.

Comment: @Dissenter yes, it will. otherwise its illogical to show that the pi- bond to shift directly to an H+.  if an electrophile hadnt attacked anything, how would any reaction proceed?

Comment: @bon yes, the initial form is also stable, but to justify that enolisation takes place you have to say that the diene is more stable.

Comment: @ritabrata I mean the lone pair attacks the proton. Which way do you draw your arrows?

Comment: @dissenter lone pairs are not capable of any movement. actually when a collision takes place , the H+ may come near the l.p. and form a bond, which on a broader view looks as if H+ goes and attacks. but still it would be wrong to say l.p. itself attacks.

Comment: Regardless of whether that's the case in reality it's convention for nucleophiles to attack electrophiles

Comment: @Dissenter lone pair are the ones which move up the to the electrophile, so the arrow is put that way. mobile nucleophiles can also attack immobile electrophiles. anyways its actually a human imagination and not the actual phenomenon, so you put in any way.

Comment: @Ritabrata I might be wrong but I believe that electrons do move in real life; electrons are the more mobile sub-atomic particles (rather than protons).

Comment: Now, @Dissenter would you say that electron jump out of their mother atom's shell and form a bond? electrons do move otherwise there wouldn't have been any photoelectric effect. but here it is completely out of context.

Comment: @Ritabrata You seem to be contradicting yourself when you say `lone pairs are not capable of any movement` and `lone pairs are the ones which move up the to the electrophile`. Your answer and comments are generally confusing and unclear. Please clarify your argument.

Comment: @bon if properly read what i said and work out a pencil and paper, you will understand what i meant to say. H+ approach but lone pair move up to form the bond.

Comment: Guys please do note again that wrong answer (if this is one) isn't equal to VLQ.